# Why I got these Error "No value accessor for form control with path: 'rowDetails -> 0 -> no'"

Tags: angular, forms, angular6, formarray, formgroups

we experiment some error when we try to use formGroup.
I need some explanations about form group.
I want create a form group with data.
The data need to display row by row.
**we use angular 8**
when I run it, I got this error :

> *No value accessor for form control with path: 'rowDetails -> 0 -> no'*

**I have this constructor of Componnent:**

```
 constructor(
    public fb: FormBuilder
    ) { 
      this.summaryForm = this.fb.group({
        rowDetails: this.fb.array([])
      })
    }
```

**I have this controller of Componnent:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.productList = (this.selectedReceiptBatch.incomeSummary as SaleSummary).sales;
    this.summaryForm = this.fb.group({
      rowDetails: this.fb.array(
        this.productList.map(x=> this.fb.group({
              'no': x.product.code,
              'desc': x.product.productClass,
              'numberx': [x.number.x],
              'numbery': x.number.y,
              'amountz': x.number.z,
              'reference': [x.reference]
        })
      )) 
    });
    console.log(this.summaryForm);
    this.formControlAvailable = true;
  }
```

**HTML :**

```
<div *ngIf="formControlAvailable">

  <div>

    <div [formGroup]="summaryForm">
      <div formArrayName="rowDetails">
        <div *ngFor="let row of summaryForm.controls.rowDetails.controls; let index = index">
          <div [formGroupName]="index">
            <div>
              <span formControlName="no" >{{row.value.no}}</span>
            </div>            
            <div>
              <span *ngIf="row?.product?.code" formControlName="desc" >
                {{row.value.desc}}
              </span>
              <div *ngIf="!row?.product?.code" ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
                  <mat-select [(value)]="row.product.code" formControlName="desc" >
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let product of cashableProducts" [value]="product.code">
                      {{product.code}}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div >
              <input type="number" [value]="row.amount.net"
                (change)="row.amount.net = parseNumber($event.target.value);calculate()" 
                formControlName='numberx' />
            </div>
            <div >
              <span formControlName='numbery' >{{ row.value.numbery }}$</span>
            </div>
            <div >
              <span formControlName='numberz' >{{ row.value.numberz }}$</span>
            </div>
            <div >
              <input formControlName='reference' type="text" class="form-control" minlength="0" [(ngModel)]="row.reference" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put `formControlName` directive only on input element, select, textarea or component that implements the interface value accessor interface.

Change this

```html
<span formControlName="no" >{{row.value.no}}</span>
```

to input element like this

```html
<input type="text" formControlName="no" >
```

If you just want to display the `no` value

```
{{row.value?.no}}
```

Comment: Thanks, and if i want only use the value for a label, can we without input and formControlName?

cause i got this error if I remove this : 

`Cannot find control with path: 'rowDetails -> 0 -> '`

Comment: just like this `<label>{{row.value?.no}}</label>` will work fine

Comment: Cause i got this error if I remove this formControlName and the input  associate to it.
`<div class="col text-center py-3">`
`<span >{{row.value?.no}}</span>`
`</div>`
 : Cannot find control with path: 'rowDetails -> 0 ->

Comment: can you share with us the `this.summaryForm` log value so I can test it

Comment: I have create a basic demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xbxypq hope this will help

Comment: @samuelcote sorry I want the productList  value not the summaryForm

Comment:  @samuelcote if this answer has solved your question please consider voting and accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. 